# How to remove a word from a linked list that has a vowel as the first character in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

This is the first time I am having to use a linkedlist. I understand how to iterate through it properly, and how to set one up. The problem I am having is I am unsure how to properly do this in combing it with checking if the first letter of a word is a vowel, and if so removing that word from the list. Here is my code so far:

```
 import java.util.*;
 public class LinkedListExample 
 {
 public static void main(String args[]) 
 {

     //Linked List Declaration 
     LinkedList<String> linkedlist = new LinkedList<String>();

     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 

     for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)//filling the list
         {
          System.out.println("What is your word?");
          String yourValue = sc.next();
          linkedlist.add(yourValue);
          sc.nextLine();
         }

      Iterator<String> i = linkedlist.iterator();
      while (i.hasNext()) 
     {
          String vowels = "aeiouy";
         //Need to remove the words with the vowels as the first letter here
     }

    while(i.hasNext())//printing out new list
    {
        System.out.println(i.next());
    }
 }
}
```

I know I must use a for loop to make this work. My first thought was using a for loop to check against my string vowels, but I was unsure how to make that work with a linked list. I am also unsure how to remove something here while using an iterator to iterate through the linked list.

Comment: use iterator:  O(1) for it.next() and it.remove()

Answer (score 0):

```
while (i.hasNext()) 
     {
          String vowels = "aeiouy";
         //Need to remove the words with the vowels as the first letter here
           boolean found = false;
           String str = i.next();

           for(int counter = 0; counter < vowels.length(); counter++)
             if(vowels.charAt(counter) == str.charAt(0)) {
                found = true;
                break;
             }
           if(found) { /* do stuff here */}
     }
```

**EDIT**:

After that, and before printing the new values, you have to reinitialize the iterator again by doing: `i = linkedlist.iterator();`. Pay attention to that. :)

Comment: I think this is going to work. However, I am getting an error at the if(vowels.charAt(counter) == i.charAt(0)) line of code. It is saying that The method charAt(int) is undefined for the type Iterator<String>. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: I've forgotten the `next()` method. I think it'll work now. Could you try it and give me a feedback?

Comment: This is what I have for the code. When I ran it i go this error:         Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(Unknown Source)
 at LinkedListExample.main(LinkedListExample.java:27)

Comment: heres the code:                                                    'if(vowels.charAt(counter) == (i.next().charAt(0))) 
                 {
                   found = true;
                   break;
                 }
                 if(found)
                 {
               i.remove();
                 }
         }'

Comment: Man, I found the problem. When you use `i.next()`, you "go to the next value", so we cannot use `i.next()` inside the inner for-loop (the way it was). See the edited code. What I changed was: first I created an String variable `str` in order to use it inside the inner for-loop. Now it works. Read the my whole edit. There is an important observation there.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> filteredList = list.stream().filter(n->n.startsWith("a")||n.startsWith("e")||n.startsWith("i")||n.startsWith("o")||n.startsWith("u")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> unique = new ArrayList<String>(list);
unique.removeAll(filteredList);
    unique.forEach(System.out::println);
```

here made an array list that contains words that starts with a,e,i,o,u and then I had created an array list that contain all elements then i removed elements that are present in filtered list unique list is your required list.  I hope my post would be helpful cheers.